# Error: Module version mismatch. when trying to launch in electron shell

Tags: node.js, mongoskin, electron

When I try to launch my app in electron shell I get the below error:
I'm using node v0.12.3
I have installed electron-prebuilt

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 43, got 14.
at Error (native)
at Object.module.(anonymous function) (ATOM_SHELL_ASAR.js:118:20)
at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ATOM_SHELL_ASAR.js:118:20)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:298:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (module.js:372:17)
at bindings (/src/git/superqa/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
at Object.<anonymous> (/src/git/superqa/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)
at Module._compile (module.js:418:26)
```

// `my main.js file` looks like this `superqa/main.js`

```
var app = require("./app/app.js");
var App = require("./src/app.js");

new App(app);
```

`//my src/app.js` looks like this `superqa/src/app.js`

```
var path = require("path");

var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

module.exports = App;

function App(app) {
  var self = this;

  this._app = app;
  this._assetDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "dist");
  this.mainWindow = null;

  app.on('ready', function() {
   self.mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1024,
      height: 768
    });
    self.mainWindow.loadUrl("http://localhost:3000/login");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the pre-built binaries were built with io.js 1.x, which uses a different (higher) ABI version than node.js. So if you want to use the pre-built version, you have to use io.js 1.x. Otherwise you will have to build electron yourself if you want to keep using node 0.12.x.

Comment: I did that and removed node_modules dir and npm install now its giving me this error for bcrypt